# Copying folder over network

Tags: cocoa, networking, remote-desktop, nsfilemanager

I'm writing an app for copying files and folders over the network to a client computer. Everything else works just peachy. It's that I don't know how to go about the file copying - I looked at NSFileManager, but it seems that this would need the network drive mounted. My goal is to simulate something like Remote Desktop's Copy File dialog, very transparently. Any ideas/help?

EDIT: Looks like an SCP wrapper, or the SCP command with NSTask may help me. Still wondering how, though :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear if you want to know how to use NSTask, or use SCP in it.

But here is a simple example of using NSTask.
Each argument for the command has to be put in an Array. 
so for example the command for

/bin/cp -R   /Users/userName/Desktop/fooFolder/fooFile.foo /Users/suerName/Desktop/fooCopyToFolder

Would be done like this.

```
NSPipe *output;


        NSTask *task;
        task = [[NSTask alloc] init];



        NSString*   cpPath = @"/bin/cp";
        NSString* sourcePath =@"/Users/userName/Desktop/fooFolder/fooFile.foo";

       NSString* finalPath = @"/Users/suerName/Desktop/fooCopyToFolder";
        [task setLaunchPath:cpPath];



        [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-R",sourcePath ,finalPath, nil]];
        output = [[NSPipe alloc] init];

        [task setStandardOutput:output];
        [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

        [task launch];
        [task waitUntilExit];

        int status = [task terminationStatus];

        if (status == 0)  {


            NSLog(@"task succeeded. %i",status);

        }   else {

            NSLog(@"task failed.%i",status);
            ;
        }
```

Comment: I understand how to use NSTask to copy local files, but I'm wondering how to use SCP to copy files over the local network. Any dice?

Comment: @Galaxas0: Same technique, except you use the path to `scp` instead of the path to `cp`, and change the arguments as needed.

Comment: So would that let me copy files over the network? I assume yes, for some very obvious reasons, but NSTask has no way to authenticate, so how would I authenticate file transfers?

Comment: Yes I have, but my application is remote-controlled from a server using another application i've already built, and I expect to type "/copy @location(/Distro/Packages/Updates/) @location(/.temp/)" and the client application (the one running scp) will copy the first location folder to the second location folder (local). I'd need to somehow work out public/private key-pairs to get this to work, I assume?

Comment: This question might help in getting feed back from NSTask.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284782/how-to-gradually-retrieve-data-from-nstask

Comment: I've decided to give up on using NSTask, as the memory overhead for files over 1GB is quite large, and it hogs CPU like no tomorrow.